# can't connect to jupyter notebook on ubuntu remote server

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed anaconda on a remote ubuntu server.  I'm trying to launch jupyter notebook on the ubuntu server and then connect to it with my local machine by replacing "localhost" in http://localhost:8888/ with the ip address of the ubuntu server. But when I paste it in to chrome on my local machine I'm getting the message that the site can't be reached.  I've don this before on other ubuntu servers and connected from my local machine.  Is there any clues what the issue might be from the messages below that I get when I launch jupyter notebook on the ubuntu server?  I notice it's asking me to enable javascript which is unusual.  By the way the token listed below is made up for the post, not real.

Code and error:

```
name1@master1:~$ jupyter notebook
[I 10:15:43.009 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from /home/name1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 10:15:43.010 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/name1/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:15:43.018 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/name1
[I 10:15:43.019 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 10:15:43.019 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:15:43.019 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=655ab123f2c6f8cfc6b9c123d159b123113a84a8433982cd
[I 10:15:43.019 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:15:43.022 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=655ab123f2c6f8cfc6b9c123d159b123113a84a8433982cd&token=655ab123f2c6f8cfc6b9c123d159b123113a84a8433982cd

Jupyter Notebook requires JavaScript.
Please enable it to proceed.
Jupyter Notebook
Quit Logout

  • Files
  • Running
  • Clusters

Select items to perform actions on them.
Duplicate Rename Move Download Shutdown View Edit
[                    ] Upload
New

  • Notebook:
  •
  • Other:
  • Text File
  • Folder
  • Terminal

[ ]  Toggle Dropdown

  • Folders
  • All Notebooks
  • Running
  • Files

  •  

File size
Last Modified
Name
Currently running Jupyter processes
Terminals
There are no terminals running.
Notebooks
There are no notebooks running.
Clusters tab is now provided by IPython parallel. See 'IPython parallel' for installation details.



























≪ ↑ ↓ Viewing <Home>
```

Comment: Did you try visiting this: `http://localhost:8888/?token=655ab123f2c6f8cfc6b9c123d159b123113a84a8433982cd&token=655ab123f2c6f8cfc6b9c123d159b123113a84a8433982cd`?

Comment: @ScottSkiles Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  Running it with localhost is what works if you're launching jupyter notebook on your local machine.  I'm launching it on a remote ubuntu server and then connecting from my local machine, which is why you have to change localhost to the ip address.